# Not getting the response from XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova

I want to search word "Cricket" in the tweets on website twitter.com. The problem is if I run this code in mobile using Phonegap then it works fine but in the local machine it not giving any response. Following is my code:

```
function appReady(){
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("GET","http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Hemant",true);
    ajax.send();

    ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
       if(ajax.readyState==4 && (ajax.status==200||ajax.status==0)){
         var data = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
         var theResults = data.results;
         var theHTML = '';

         for(var i=0;i<theResults.length;i++){
           alert(theResults[i].text);
         }
         document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = theHTML;
       }
    }
}
```

The alert showing the error : ***`JSON.parse: unexpected end of data`***

Tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please indent your code!

Comment: silly question, but from you 'local' machine, have you circumnavigated the **'XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://search.twitter.com/search.jsonp?q=Hemant. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.'** issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to do it with Jquery and the GetJSON function? something like this:

```
function appReady(){
  $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Hemant&callback=?', function(json) {
      var theHtml = "";
      var theResults = json.results;
      for(var i=0;i<theResults.length;i++){
           theHtml += theResults[i].text;
         }
      $("#main").html(theHtml);
  });
}​
```

fiddle example [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/eBUcv/2/). (changed the appReady() to document.ready)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly here's a workable answer with no jQuery.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callTwitterSearch() {
          var url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Hemant&callback=parseRequest";
          //create and inject the script element
          var script = document.createElement('script');
          script.setAttribute('src', url);
          document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
      }

      function parseRequest(response) {
//This response object is the actual JSON parsed response from twitters api.
          alert(response.results.length);//Simply print the result list's size
      }
    </script>
    </head>
      <body onLoad="callTwitterSearch()">
      <body>
    </html>
```

Secondly,

In jQuery, if you specify the callback=?, you are effectively changing the call from a **json** to a **jsonp** call. jsonp is explained nicely [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

**json** calls have to be made from the same domain. 
**jsonp** calls are for cross domain calls. since your local machine (and I'm assuming here :)) is not on the twitter domain, your call fails.

Answer (score 0):

`'<div class="tweet"'` seems to be missing a closing bracket, which is likely mucking up the rest of your HTML string, causing it to be parsed differently than you'd like.

You are misusing `eval` here.  What you meant to do was `var data = eval(ajax.responseText);`.  **However**, this is really bad idea, since a network attacker could replace your JSON response with something like `window.close()` or something even nastier.  What you should do is `var data = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);` and use a [JSON library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) for browsers without support for the `JSON` object.

Comment: I tried to alerting `simple alert(ajax.responseText);` but it showing blank